# error while adding development keyhash in developer.facebook.com

Tags: android, facebook

i am currently making a demo app for integrating Facebook sso and i made a debug keyhash for login via facebook but when i am adding development keyhash in facebook developers site its asking me for the release keyhash at the same time and i dont want to upload this demo to the playstore and its not allowing me to finish the process.

Please anyone suggest me something so that i can proceed.[image: Getting error while not putting Release key hash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void generateHashKeyForFacebook(Context context) throws Exception {
        try {   
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.yourPackageName", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("FBKeyHash >>> ", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Just put this function to your activity and see your log cat for obtaining your hash key
Below is the link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

[image: SANDBOX IMAGE]

Comment: this i used but then too how to finish this process without finishing it how can i move forward ? Even i got the keyhash and put it into development keyhash but with putting release keyhash its not working ahead.

Comment: have you on from sandbox mode ?

Comment: i searched for sandbox mode but i am not getting it anywhere

Comment: From left side pannel select status and review and on the right side you can find the sandbox mode

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer now its working but when i clicked on login via facebook its not managing the session and when i traced the log it gives me 09-23 16:10:19.422: I/System.out(22977): Session:-->>{Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:myappid}

Comment: And its also giving me the Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.

Comment: but can you guide me on this as i am facing problem since long.

Comment: Have you declare app id in to your menifiest like <string name="app_id">999999999999999</string>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" /> follow above link and tutorial then you wont face any problem

Comment: yes i did all things.. but i suppose there might be some problem with token

Comment: Actually previously i made 3 apps and its uploaded to the playstore with this functionality but now this is not live on playstore and its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61747/discussion-between-riddhi-shah-and-hetal-patel).